# Labeling loops in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I need to label the edges and the loop on this graph, but I'm having some trouble.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n2) at (0,8) {$x_{2}$};
  \node (n1) at (-3,6)  {$x_{1}$};
  \node (n3) at (3,6)  {$x_{3}$};
  \node (n4) at (2,2) {$x_{4}$};
  \node (n5) at (-2,2)  {$x_{5}$};
\foreach \from/\to in {n1/n3,n1/n5,n5/n4,n3/n4,n1/n2}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\draw[bend left] (n2) to (n3);
\draw[bend right] (n2) to (n3);
\draw(n4) to [out=160,in=100,distance=3cm] (n4);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can add `node`s after `to` or `to [<with options>]`, for example: `\draw[bend left] (n2) to node {foo} (n3);`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add nodes along the path if you pass them between `to` (after possible options) and the following coordinates. By default, the `midway` position is used which you can change by using the `pos` option or one of the following short-cuts (which correspond to the `pos`ition in parentheses):

```
at start         (pos = 0    )
very near start  (pos = 0.125)
near start       (pos = 0.25 )
midway           (pos = 0.5  )
near end         (pos = 0.75 )
very near end    (pos = 0.875)
at end           (pos = 1    )
```

These options and their use are explained in the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/PGFmanual) in section 16.8 “Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly”, pp. 190ff., and the following section 16.9 “Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Implicitly”, pp. 193f.

They also use the `every node` style so to avoid that they use the same style as your main nodes, do

```
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={…}]
  \node (n1) … {$x_1$};
  \node (n2) … {$x_2$};
\end{scope}

\draw (n1) to node {$t_{1,2}$} (n2);
```

Though, in your case I would specify the nodes and their position differently, namely with polar coordinates.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto=right]
  \foreach \cnt in {1,...,5}
    \node[circle, outer sep=+0pt, fill=blue!20] (n\cnt)
                                             at (3.25*360/5-\cnt*360/5:2) {$x_\cnt$};

  \path [every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=+.1667em}] 
        (n1) edge node       {$t_{1,3}$} (n3)
             edge node       {$t_{1,5}$} (n5)
             edge node[swap] {$t_{1,2}$} (n2)
        (n4) edge node {$t_{3,4}$}       (n3)
             edge[out=160, in=100, distance=1.6cm]
                  node[swap] {$t_{4}$}   (n4)
             edge node[swap] {$t_{4,5}$} (n5)
        (n2) edge[bend left]  node[swap] {$t_{2,3}$} (n3)
             edge[bend right] node[swap] {$t_{3,2}$} (n3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realize you are likely looking for an answer within the context of `tikz`, but there are non-`tikz` approaches that, for certain types of problems, may have advantages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newsavebox{\mypic}
\sbox\mypic{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n2) at (0,8) {$x_{2}$};
  \node (n1) at (-3,6)  {$x_{1}$};
  \node (n3) at (3,6)  {$x_{3}$};
  \node (n4) at (2,2) {$x_{4}$};
  \node (n5) at (-2,2)  {$x_{5}$};
\foreach \from/\to in {n1/n3,n1/n5,n5/n4,n3/n4,n1/n2}
\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\draw[bend left] (n2) to (n3);
\draw[bend right] (n2) to (n3);
\draw(n4) to [out=160,in=100,distance=3cm] (n4);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\bottominset{$s_{12}$}{%
\bottominset{$s_{23}$}{%
\bottominset{$s_{34}$}{%
\bottominset{$s_{45}$}{%
\bottominset{$s_{51}$}{%
\bottominset{loop}{%
  \usebox{\mypic}%
}{1.6cm}{1.8cm}
}{1.2cm}{0.3cm}
}{0.1cm}{1.7cm}
}{1.4cm}{3.3cm}
}{3.2cm}{3.0cm}
}{3.0cm}{0.8cm}
\end{document}
```

[image]